# Why are my dots vertical in slick slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var $slickElement = $('.slideshow');

    $slickElement.slick({
      autoplay: true,
      dots: true,
    });

});
```

```css
*{
  outline:none;
}
/* spacer */
.spacer{
  height:150px;
  width:100%;
}
.spacer2{
  height:20px;
  width:100%;
}
/* spacer ends */

/* slider styles */
.sd_master_wrapper{
    position: relative; 
    max-width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    border-radius:10px;
    z-index:9999;
}
.sdtestBg3{
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -40px;
    left: 10%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 18px 52.8537px rgb(215 228 249 / 50%);
    z-index:1;
}
.sdtestBg2{
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -22px;
    left: 5%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 18px 52.8537px rgb(215 228 249 / 50%);
    z-index:2;
}

.sd_scroll {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 180px;
    overflow: auto;
}
    
.slideshow {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 300px;
    height: auto;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 18px 52.8537px rgba(215, 228, 249, 0.5);
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-image: url(https://farsighttechnologies.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/quote1.png), url(https://farsighttechnologies.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/quote.png);
    background-position: top 15px left 15px, bottom 40% right 15px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 180px, 180px;
    z-index:3;
}
button.slick-prev.slick-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    bottom: -80px;
    right: 160px;
    background: transparent;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(https://farsighttechnologies.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/left-icon.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
button.slick-next.slick-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -82px;
    right: 105px;
    background: transparent;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    height: 18px;
    width: 40px;
    background-image: url(https://farsighttechnologies.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/right-icon.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.pagingInfo {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
.sdCustomSliderHeadig {
    color: #94A2B3;
    font-family: "Poppins", Sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    text-align: center;
}
.sdCustomSliderBtn{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: montserrat;
    background: #E31C3A;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 12px 25px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.sdAllContent{
    width:75%;
    margin:auto;
}
.thumbnail img {
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.content{
    display:block !important;
    padding: 5px;
}
.SdClientName {
    text-align: center;
    color: #272D4E;
    font-family: "Poppins", Sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.SdClientDesc {
    text-align: center;
    color: #7854F7;
    font-family: "Poppins", Sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/* style for moblile */
@media (max-width:576px){
.sd_scroll {
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    max-height:240px;
}

.thumbnail, .btnNtxt{
    width: 100% !important;
    display: block !important;
}

}
/* scroll bar */
/* total width */
.sd_scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color:transparent;
    width:6px;
}

/* background of the scrollbar except button or resizer */
.sd_scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color:transparent;
}
.sd_scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
    background-color:transparent;
}

/* scrollbar itself */
.sd_scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color:#babac0;
    border-radius:16px;
    
}
.sd_scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color:#a0a0a5;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins' rel='stylesheet'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>


<div class="spacer2"></div>
<center>
<center>
<div class="spacer"></div>


<div class="sd_master_wrapper"> 
    <div class="sdtestBg2"></div>
    <div class="sdtestBg3"></div>
    <div class="slideshow">
        
        <div class="content"> <!-- slide 1 -->
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://farsighttechnologies.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/AC.jpg"> 
            </div>
            <div class="btnNtxt"> 
                <div class="sdAllContent"> 
                    
                    <div class="sd_scroll">
                    <h1 class="sdCustomSliderHeadig">A wonderful, user-friendly HR solution! Farsight HR Solution helped us implement ESS (Employee Self Service) portal for our large enterprise, which made both employees and Human Resources more productive. User-oriented interface and professional team.</h1> 
                    </div>
                    <p class="SdClientName">Vice President</p>
                    <p class="SdClientDesc">CPF India</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="content"> <!-- slide 2 -->
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://farsighttechnologies.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/MS.jpg"> 
            </div>
            <div class="btnNtxt"> 
                <div class="sdAllContent"> 
                    
                    <div class="sd_scroll">
                    <h1 class="sdCustomSliderHeadig">For us, Farsight has become much more than a software solution provider. Farsight has been our helping hand with implementing business automation. The team's expertise, skill, and commitment to excellence are what makes them so great.</h1> 
                    </div>
                    <p class="SdClientName">Head IT</p>
                    <p class="SdClientDesc">Mushahi Auto Parts</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="content"> <!-- slide 3 -->
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://farsighttechnologies.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/RR.jpg"> 
            </div>
            <div class="btnNtxt"> 
                <div class="sdAllContent"> 
                    
                    <div class="sd_scroll">
                    <h1 class="sdCustomSliderHeadig">I would like to place on record my sincere appreciation for helping us to automate the Salary Revision Exercise and also the Leave Management System at Schneider Electric India. We have had huge challenges in the past to manage these 2 complex exercises and it was a nightmare for HR every March/April. However when we engaged you and worked closely to develop a Software Tool customised for Schneider Electric, our lives have become very much easy. What used to be a pain for us became a huge gain for HR Shared Services.</h1> 
                    </div>
                    <p class="SdClientName">Vice President – India HR Services</p>
                    <p class="SdClientDesc">Schneider Electric</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="content"> <!-- slide 4 -->
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://farsighttechnologies.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/testimonial.png"> 
            </div>
            <div class="btnNtxt"> 
                <div class="sdAllContent">
                    <div class="sd_scroll">
                    <h1 class="sdCustomSliderHeadig">With Farsight’s Employee Self Service Portal, our Vision of implementing an HR Software in Honda R&D (India) could be realized for the easy and smooth functioning of operations. Processes and Policies were well understood by the Team and extended a solution in the System, we look forward for more such customizations where customer is always given a priority. We wish them success for all the future endeavors. </h1>
                    </div>  
                    <p class="SdClientName">General Manager – Administration Head</p>
                    <p class="SdClientDesc">Honda R&D (India) Pvt. Ltd. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
</div>  
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

My slick slider dots are vertically aligned, and i havent seen anything like this in other slick slider codes. Why is this and how can I fix it? Also, why do i have both numbers and dots? I have tried editing the css with other people's css but it isnt working, that why im asking, in case any of you can help me.
This is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var $slickElement = $('.slideshow');

    $slickElement.slick({
      autoplay: true,
      dots: true,
    });

});
```

```
*{
  outline:none;
}
/* spacer */
.spacer{
  height:150px;
  width:100%;
}
.spacer2{
  height:20px;
  width:100%;
}
/* spacer ends */

/* slider styles */
.sd_master_wrapper{
    position: relative; 
    max-width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    border-radius:10px;
    z-index:9999;
}
.sdtestBg3{
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -40px;
    left: 10%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 18px 52.8537px rgb(215 228 249 / 50%);
    z-index:1;
}
.sdtestBg2{
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -22px;
    left: 5%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 18px 52.8537px rgb(215 228 249 / 50%);
    z-index:2;
}

.sd_scroll {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 180px;
    overflow: auto;
}
    
.slideshow {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 300px;
    height: auto;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 18px 52.8537px rgba(215, 228, 249, 0.5);
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-image: url(https://farsighttechnologies.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/quote1.png), url(https://farsighttechnologies.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/quote.png);
    background-position: top 15px left 15px, bottom 40% right 15px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 180px, 180px;
    z-index:3;
}
button.slick-prev.slick-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    bottom: -80px;
    right: 160px;
    background: transparent;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(https://farsighttechnologies.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/left-icon.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
button.slick-next.slick-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -82px;
    right: 105px;
    background: transparent;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    height: 18px;
    width: 40px;
    background-image: url(https://farsighttechnologies.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/right-icon.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.pagingInfo {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
.sdCustomSliderHeadig {
    color: #94A2B3;
    font-family: "Poppins", Sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    text-align: center;
}
.sdCustomSliderBtn{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: montserrat;
    background: #E31C3A;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 12px 25px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.sdAllContent{
    width:75%;
    margin:auto;
}
.thumbnail img {
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.content{
    display:block !important;
    padding: 5px;
}
.SdClientName {
    text-align: center;
    color: #272D4E;
    font-family: "Poppins", Sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.SdClientDesc {
    text-align: center;
    color: #7854F7;
    font-family: "Poppins", Sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/* style for moblile */
@media (max-width:576px){
.sd_scroll {
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    max-height:240px;
}

.thumbnail, .btnNtxt{
    width: 100% !important;
    display: block !important;
}

}
/* scroll bar */
/* total width */
.sd_scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color:transparent;
    width:6px;
}

/* background of the scrollbar except button or resizer */
.sd_scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color:transparent;
}
.sd_scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
    background-color:transparent;
}

/* scrollbar itself */
.sd_scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color:#babac0;
    border-radius:16px;
    
}
.sd_scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color:#a0a0a5;
}
```

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins' rel='stylesheet'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>


<div class="spacer2"></div>
<center>
Crafted by : <a href="http://codersandip.com/" target="_blank">Sandip Das</a> <br>
 Warning: Do not copy paste our original content in your website, like client name, review, images, etc. <center>
<div class="spacer"></div>


<div class="sd_master_wrapper"> 
    <div class="sdtestBg2"></div>
    <div class="sdtestBg3"></div>
    <div class="slideshow">
        
        <div class="content"> <!-- slide 1 -->
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://farsighttechnologies.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/AC.jpg"> 
            </div>
            <div class="btnNtxt"> 
                <div class="sdAllContent"> 
                    
                    <div class="sd_scroll">
                    <h1 class="sdCustomSliderHeadig">A wonderful, user-friendly HR solution! Farsight HR Solution helped us implement ESS (Employee Self Service) portal for our large enterprise, which made both employees and Human Resources more productive. User-oriented interface and professional team.</h1> 
                    </div>
                    <p class="SdClientName">Vice President</p>
                    <p class="SdClientDesc">CPF India</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="content"> <!-- slide 2 -->
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://farsighttechnologies.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/MS.jpg"> 
            </div>
            <div class="btnNtxt"> 
                <div class="sdAllContent"> 
                    
                    <div class="sd_scroll">
                    <h1 class="sdCustomSliderHeadig">For us, Farsight has become much more than a software solution provider. Farsight has been our helping hand with implementing business automation. The team's expertise, skill, and commitment to excellence are what makes them so great.</h1> 
                    </div>
                    <p class="SdClientName">Head IT</p>
                    <p class="SdClientDesc">Mushahi Auto Parts</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="content"> <!-- slide 3 -->
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://farsighttechnologies.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/RR.jpg"> 
            </div>
            <div class="btnNtxt"> 
                <div class="sdAllContent"> 
                    
                    <div class="sd_scroll">
                    <h1 class="sdCustomSliderHeadig">I would like to place on record my sincere appreciation for helping us to automate the Salary Revision Exercise and also the Leave Management System at Schneider Electric India. We have had huge challenges in the past to manage these 2 complex exercises and it was a nightmare for HR every March/April. However when we engaged you and worked closely to develop a Software Tool customised for Schneider Electric, our lives have become very much easy. What used to be a pain for us became a huge gain for HR Shared Services.</h1> 
                    </div>
                    <p class="SdClientName">Vice President – India HR Services</p>
                    <p class="SdClientDesc">Schneider Electric</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="content"> <!-- slide 4 -->
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://farsighttechnologies.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/testimonial.png"> 
            </div>
            <div class="btnNtxt"> 
                <div class="sdAllContent">
                    <div class="sd_scroll">
                    <h1 class="sdCustomSliderHeadig">With Farsight’s Employee Self Service Portal, our Vision of implementing an HR Software in Honda R&D (India) could be realized for the easy and smooth functioning of operations. Processes and Policies were well understood by the Team and extended a solution in the System, we look forward for more such customizations where customer is always given a priority. We wish them success for all the future endeavors. </h1>
                    </div>  
                    <p class="SdClientName">General Manager – Administration Head</p>
                    <p class="SdClientDesc">Honda R&D (India) Pvt. Ltd. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
</div>  
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

Comment: You have duplicate code in there, this is TLDR.  If you want to create a horizontal list you should check out W3s guide on a horizontal navigation menu: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp though It's likely an issue with your `display` css attribute, and to get rid of the dots: `list-style-type: none;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add only **minimal code** to reproduce the problem in your questions, thanks.

I see you're using slick-carousel, looking at [the docs in npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slick-carousel), it says that if you want the default styling you must also add this to the header.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
```

If you don't add that you must style it yourself.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $slickElement = $('.slideshow');

  $slickElement.slick({
    autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
  });
});
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins' rel='stylesheet'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />

<!-- Add this -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" />

<!-- Add this -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slideshow" data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 4, "slidesToScroll": 4}'>
  <div><h3>1</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2</h3></div>
  <div><h3>3</h3></div>
  <div><h3>4</h3></div>
  <div><h3>5</h3></div>
  <div><h3>6</h3></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you!! I added the code you told me to the header and it worked. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

[

```css
ul.slick-dots{
    list-style-type: none;  
}
.slick-dots li{
    display: inline;
}
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5dD6.png)